# Recursively creating hardlinks using python

Tags: python, directory, directory-structure, hardlink

What I basically would like to do is `cp -Rl dir1 dir2`. But as I understand it, python only provides `shutils.copytree(src,dst)` which actually copies the files, but has no possibility of hardlinking the files instead.

I know that I could invoke the `cp` command using the `subprocess` module, but I'd rather like to find a cleaner (pythonic) way to do so.

So is there an easy way to do so or do I have to implement it myself recursing through the directories?

Comment: The directory traversal is pretty easy to do, so why not try it?

Comment: It is not about trying or not trying: The question rather wants to say "I can't imagine that this hasn't been done before hundreds of times and therefore must be available in module xy". Reinventing the wheel all the time just doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It's possible in Python stdlib using [`shutil`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html?highlight=shutil#shutil.copytree) and [`os.link`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.link):

```
import os, shutil

shutil.copytree(src, dst, copy_function=os.link)
```

Comment: @twall: Note this is Python 3 only. In Python 2, you might modify the example code: http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html#copytree-example

Comment: It's not at all clear from the Python docs if `copy_function=os.link` actually exists, or need to be created artificially. (See examples in the linked docs.) If it does, then also `os.symlink` should be possible.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a pure python hardcopy function. Should work the same as `cp -Rl src dst`

```
import os
from os.path import join, abspath

def hardcopy(src, dst):
    working_dir = os.getcwd()
    dest = abspath(dst)
    os.mkdir(dst)
    os.chdir(src)
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk('.'):
        curdest = join(dst, root)
        for d in dirs:
            os.mkdir(join(curdst, d))
        for f in files:
            fromfile = join(root, f)
            to = join(curdst, f)
            os.link(fromfile, to)
    os.chdir(working_dir)
```